# How to display an image in PHP file

Tags: php, html

UPDATE: I managed to get it working by not using absolute file paths (../Images\City of Bath College Logo.jpg).

2nd UPDATE: Also used it for the CSS file too and now it works 'the HTML way'.

I'm having an issue displaying an image in my PHP file (the City of Bath College logo). If I save the file as an HTML file (and change the way CSS is linked) it works fine, but it doesn't work as PHP. I've tried searching for an answer for a few hours with no luck. I imagine it's just some newbie/rookie mistake. Thanks in advance for help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>

    <title>Project Cherrypicker | Login</title>

    <!-- Link CSS File -->
    <style><?php include 'F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Project Cherrypicker\CSS\LoginPage.css'; ?></style>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Login Form -->
    <div class = "LoginForm">

        <!-- City of Bath College Logo -->
        <img src = "F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Project Cherrypicker\Images\City of Bath College Logo.jpg" class = "Logo">

        <!-- Headers -->
        <h1>Project Cherrypicker</h1>
        <h2>Log In</h2>

        <form action = "HomePage.html" method = "Post">

            <!-- Username Box -->
            <label for = "Username">Username</label>
            <input type = "text" name = "Username" placeholder = "Enter Username" required>

            <!-- Password Box -->
            <label for = "Password">Password</label>
            <input type = "password" name = "Password" placeholder = "Enter Password" required>

            <!-- Submit Button -->
            <input type = "submit" name = "Submit" value = "Login">

            <!-- Website Credit -->
            <p id = "LoginFormCredit">Website created by Jordan Rowe.</p>

        </form>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: That's an ...unusual way to handle CSS, but there's no reason why your `<img src>` tag should be failing. Using spaces and an absolute path is generally not a good idea, but it should still display the image, assuming you have it at the right location. Remember, once you upload the file to a server, you'll need to change the path. Have you tried checking your F12 Developer Tools to see where it is trying to load the image from?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I plan on changing links and stuff later, but only once I know how to get it working. At the moment, I'm focusing on design, hence why I've not got anything in the PHP file at the moment that I couldn't just stick in a HTML file.

Comment: The spaces and file path shouldn't be a problem for local development. I assume it's just a caching issue. Try `CTRL + F5` in addition to `SHIFT + CTRL + R`. I'd also recommend using the "HTML way" for handling the CSS file (`link href`), as inline styles  have high specificity.

Comment: My CSS doesn't work when I use the HTML way, for some reason. That's why I have to use it this way. Unless I'm (probably) doing something wrong?

Comment: Yish, spaces in filepaths. Just say *no* to spaces in filepaths... even if this is a development sandbox ;)

Comment: Your CSS is included inline rather than as a separate external file when you use php include. Since you are using php functions, you have to use a php file, a php processor. A flat html file wouldn't make any sense of a php function.

Your page can be made without php. Read about basic html web page building.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in PHP schould look like this.

```
<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(file_get_contents("F:\XAMPP\htdocs\Project Cherrypicker\Images\City of Bath College Logo.jpg")); ?>'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are bad practice inside of file paths, either re-name the file or change the html src to have '%20' where the spaces are, as this represents a single space.